# Manipulating classes with jquery

Tags: jquery, dom-manipulation

I have a select box with values:
apple-80
apple-100
apple-120
apple-300

I have: `<body class="fruit apple-120 otherclass anotherclass">`

I want to manipulate the body class "apple-120" to get replaced by any of selected value from the select box while keeping the fruit, otherclass, anotherclass, class untouched.

So far I created this:

```
$.fn.classSwitcher = function(options) {
  var baseOptions = {
    classTarget: 'body',
    oldClass: 'apple-120'
    };

  var options = $.extend(baseOptions, options);

  return this.each(function() {
         $(this).click(function() { 
           var t = $(this);
           var optionVal = t.val();
             $(options.classTarget).removeClass(options.oldClass).addClass(optionVal);
         });
  });
};
```

Then I have:

```
$('#sel option').classSwitcher();
```

This replaced the class, but on the next click of the select box, more select option values are added as new classes, which was not what I wanted.

I just want to replace "apple-120" with a new value, not adding more. Any other click will just replace the same target class.

Plus, I also wanted to grab all select box values to keep them as a condition to narrow down selection on those classes. Says, if a class matches any of the values in the select box, do something.

Any hint would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you updating the value in `options.oldClass` in any way?

Comment: options.oldClass should be replaced with any value from select box. Max answer did it. Only waiting for the grabbing select values part. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not updating `options.oldClass` so it always tries to remove the original `apple-120`. You should set it to the class that's being assigned when you update:

```
...
     $(this).click(function() { 
       var t = $(this);
       var optionVal = t.val();
       $(options.classTarget).removeClass(options.oldClass).addClass(optionVal);
       options.oldClass = optionVal;
     });
...
```

Comment: Hi, Max. You addressed my problem. I mistook it fot Lachlan. The answers are jumping around too :) Any hint on grabbing all select box values too? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by grabbing select box values. You can simply get all the `<option>` elements via `$('#sel option').toArray()` then get their `.value`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remember values from previous invocations of click, you could store the value with  [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

```
$(this).click(function() { 
     var val = $(this).val();
     if (val != $(this).data('previous')) {
         $(this).data('previous', val );
         // ...
     }
});
```

Comment: This one works so far, just missing the closing ). I'll update my finding with other answer. Thanks.

Comment: Oops, wrong pick. Your code actually broke. Any hint? I tested along with Max answers and mistook it for you and cache as usual.